# Why is error shown when looping through .wav files in a directory but works OK when not looping?

Tags: python, audio, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, wav

The following runs successfully:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

filename = 'audiofiles/myaudiofile.wav'

# initiailse the recognizer
r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.AudioFile(filename) as source:
    # listen for the data (load audio to memory)
    audio_data = r.record(source)
    # recognize (convert from speech to text)
    text = r.recognize_google(audio_data)
    print(text)
```

...and outputs the text of the words spoken in the .wav file.

When I run the following code (to check it will work for multiple files which I'll soon add to this directory):

```
import os

directory = 'audiofiles'

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    with sr.AudioFile(filename) as source:
        # listen for the data (load audio to memory)
        audio_data = r.record(source)
        # recognize (convert from speech to text)
        text = r.recognize_google(audio_data)
        print(text)
        print('---')
```

...the text is output correctly but then its followed by the error below. Why? How can I fix this?

> ValueError: Audio file could not be read as PCM WAV, AIFF/AIFF-C, or Native FLAC; check if file is corrupted or in another format

Comment: try adding a print(filename) as the first line in your loop, what is the first file you see?

Comment: Thanks Chris. The filename printed is 'myaudiofile.wav'

Comment: I just printed the list of files in the directory using `list_of_filenames = os.listdir(directory)` and it looks like there is an extra hidden file that is not a .wav file. How can I ask it to just look at the .wav files?

Comment: Solved it! Added `if filename.endswith('.wav'):`

Answer (score 1):

There was a hidden file that wasn't a .wav file. So I added `if filename.endswith('.wav'):` like this:

```
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith('.wav'):
        with sr.AudioFile(filename) as source:
            # listen for the data (load audio to memory)
            audio_data = r.record(source)
            # recognize (convert from speech to text)
            text = r.recognize_google(audio_data)
            print(text)
            print('---')
```

...and it worked successfully.